# Getting java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry for SimpleJavaMail

Tags: java, android, gradle, jar

While building apk for my project, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/simplejavamail/email/AttachmentResource.class
```

Here's my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.parassidhu.cdlumaths"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "8g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:3.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.hotchemi:android-rate:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'org.simplejavamail:simple-java-mail:4.1.1'
    compile files('libs/simple-java-mail-4.1.1.jar')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I think I will have to change something with

```
'org.simplejavamail:simple-java-mail:4.1.1'
```

I have no idea what's wrong. I can test the app fine but when I Rebuild project/build apk/generate signed apk, I get this error. Sometimes the duplicate entry points to different class than AttachmentResource.class.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your including the same dependency twice.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'org.simplejavamail:simple-java-mail:4.1.1'
    compile files('libs/simple-java-mail-4.1.1.jar') // <- this is the same jar as your pulling from maven in the line above
}
```

remove this line and retry `compile files('libs/simple-java-mail:4.1.1')`

Comment: When I removed the line you told, I still got the exception. But when I kept it and removed the other one, the error is gone! But, actual library functions are not working. Error: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14492668/Error.txt Please please help. It's urgent. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you choose to use the `jar` directly then you would also have to include all it's dependencies.  You can find all the dependencies for `org.simplejavamail:simple-java-mail:4.1.1` in it's `pom` here: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/simplejavamail/simple-java-mail/4.1.1/simple-java-mail-4.1.1.pom.  Of course if you use the artifact resolution in gradle then you get all those in your classpath without automagically.

Comment: In the case of your second error looks like `org.slf4j` is a second tier dependency for using `simple-java-mail`.  Basically `simple-java-mail` relies on the code from `slf4j`, instead of including all that code they just include the pom reference and the build system will add `simple-java-mail`'s dependencies

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. Why doesn't kepping the line you told work? That should have automated the process. Although will give ur way a try right away

Comment: Perhaps another lib is also including `simple-mail-java`.  you could use `./gradlew dependencies` and find where the second inclusion then remove it  `compile('offending.project.1.2.3') { exclude 'org.simplejavemail:simple-java-mail' }`  Then your project would only see the dependency you explicitly included

Comment: Sorry to ask but can you tell me where to use ./gradlew dependencies command

Comment: `gradlew` is the wrapper command, it's usually in the project's home directory.  Just call `gradle` like you usually do but instead of using the task `build` use the task `dependencies`

Comment: Well well well... jumping back to above comments, I now removed the line you told and kept the other one (it worked after removing some of jars). I thought everything will work now.. But here's another error: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14492668/Error2.txt. The error line number has changed. Before, it was at starting point of where library's function had started. Now it points to the last line where actual email send is requested. Seems the library is well integrated now. Something else is wrong